# Replacing RDoc with YARD in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc, yard, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Is it possible to replace RDoc with YARD in Rails 4.2? I'd like `rake doc:app` to invoke YARD rather than RDoc.

In my Gemfile I replaced `sdoc` with YARD (`gem 'yard', '~> 0.8.0', group: :doc`) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [official Github Project for YARD](https://github.com/lsegal/yard), you can do that by running `yard server` which spawns a new server in http://localhost:8808/ for your documentation.